# Differential geometry and the $P \vec A= \vec F$ equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, differential-geometry, pressure, continuum-mechanics

How does one write

$$\vec F = P \vec A$$

(where $\vec F$ is the force. $P$ is the pressure and $\vec A$ is the area) in the language of differential forms? I'm confused cause $\vec F$ is a one form and $\vec A$ is a $2$ form? Does this mean this equation cannot hold for a relativistic gas?

Comment: Wikipedia [Pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure#Formula)

Comment: In general pressure needs to be generalized to the stress tensor, giving $F^i = \sigma^{ij} A_j$. Also, differential forms don't work here because the stress tensor isn't antisymmetric.

Comment: Here's the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179158/how-to-introduce-stress-tensor-on-manifolds